# Input File element tag is not working in internal Web tool based on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, file-upload

I am developing a web page in an internal tool that uses IE11. The tool has different infrastructure where not all native Javascript code works. We have included the jQuery library.

The issue is with reading the file from the file `input` element. After I browse and select a file, the code is able to read the inputFile element with no issues:

```
var selectedFile = $('#inputFile');
```

However, it does not find any files under this element:

```
if (selectedFile.files.length > 0)
```

I tried other alternatives which do not work too:

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputFile');
var file = input.files[0];
```

OR

```
var x = document.getElementById("inputFile");
if ('files' in x) {​​​​​​​​}
```

Answer (score 0):

`selectedFile` is a jQuery object, whereas the `files` collection only exists on the Element object within that.

Either of these approaches will retrieve the `files` collection from the Element within the jQuery object:

```
// #1
var $selectedFile = $('#inputFile');
if ($selectedFile[0].files.length > 0) {
  // do something...
}

// #2
var $selectedFile = $('#inputFile');
if ($selectedFile.prop('files').length > 0) {
  // do something...
}
```

Note that I prefixed the `selectedFile` variable with a `$`. This is standard practice when working with jQuery as it makes it clear that the variable holds a jQuery object, not an Element.